# Python re.sub on multiple non-similar characters

Tags: regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to use a regex to extract a part of an email.

For example, given `wellness.good@gmail.com` I want to get `wellness` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you use the re module in Python.  A simple option would be to try to get all word characters at the beginning of a string:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'^(\w+)')
first_word = regex.findall('wellness.good@gmail.com')[0]
```

The title of your question makes me think you are looking for the + modifier, which stands for 1 or more matches.

Comment: In this case, I want every user to get their username to be the first bit of their email before the @. This means that, I do not know the first letter to their email

Comment: That doesn't match your question.  However if you want that, then the regex would be: `r'^([^@]+)@'` and you could even skip the r flag (though I think it is good to add to all regexes to avoid problems when you add backslashes as things change).